# How does the automatic subjective filter work?

Tags: discussion, quality-filter, subjective, subjective-warning

I just entered a question titled: "What’s the best way to serialize / deserialize a `Dictionary<String,String>` in .Net 2.0?"

And the system told me: "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed."

How is that working currently?
What are you looking for in the title to flag something as "potentially subjective"?
Is it because I asked for "the best way" to do something?

Comment: @Glorfindel wouldnt reversing the duplicate be more usefull, as this post contains an authorative answer?

Comment: That idea has some merit; however, I can't reopen this question anymore...

Answer (score 40, accepted):

here:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(s, 
@"\bbest\b|\bworst\b|\bhardest\b|\byour?\b|\bfavou?rite\b", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Thank you Jeff! That explains it.
Should I take from this that these words are frowned upon in question titles? Or is this just a warning?

Comment: I got those words by scanning about a hundred closed subjective questions that were not good fits on Stack Overflow. Those words aren't wrong per se but they do not bode well for a question.

Comment: Thanks! Curiosity Satisfied :-)

Comment: One minor issue is that it will trigger on "how do you do x?", which is a common construct for non-subjective questions.

Comment: The regex might be better written as `"\b(?:best|worst|hardest|your?|favou?rite)\b"` so you don't have so many `\b` escapes, and they're not immediately followed by text.

Comment: `"How does best-fit memory allocation work?"` matches that regex. `"What's better, Java or C#?"` doesn't.

Comment: `"What is a Half-Carry and how do you calculate it?"` matches this and is not subjective, but `"What is a Half-Carry and how does _one_ calculate it?"` looks too formal.

Comment: Using (a part of) *The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed* in the title of this question would've made it easier to search.

Comment: It's been 6 years since the last comment here, but I think the problem with "you" still needs to be addressed. "you" by itself is not an indicator of subjectiveness. Simply removing the "?" in "your?" would excise the vast majority of the subjectiveness filter's false positives.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is it looks for words like "best", "favorite", "your".  I'd be interested in knowing just what words trigger it, and how that list was determined.  Not that it matters much, I'm just as curious as you.

Comment: Nice guess. You were almost right on. :)

Answer (score 5):

It's done by a simple regex as posted by Jeff.  The regex matches the following words:

- Best
- Worst
- Hardest
- You
- Your
- Favorite
- Favourite

It is important to note that avoiding the above words does not make your question any less subjective - "Best management tool" is inherently subjective - the warning is not there to tell you to avoid certain words, but to avoid the question altogether, or to re-word it so it can be evaluated objectively and measurably so that the answer is the same for everyone in your situation.

-Adam

Comment: And as others have commented (ages ago), *using* those words doesn't necessarily make your question subjective.  That's the trouble with all heuristics.