# Should I reword a question to avoid triggering the "subjective question" warning, or does it not matter?

Tags: discussion, edits, subjective-warning

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222184/do-you-need-to-lock-or-mark-as-volatile-when-accessing-a-simple-boolean-flag-in-c) on SO that triggered a "subjective question" warning.

I found the [reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work/4435#4435) on why this warning was triggered, but my question is does it matter?

The question isn't subjective, there should be a clearly defined technical answer. Now I know the reasons, does it make any difference? Is it worth editing the question to remove the word that triggered the subjective warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've obviously seen the method through which subjective questions are identified.  It's not exactly foolproof.  If your question isn't subjective, go ahead and ask it.  The warning doesn't close your question; it doesn't matter what it says.

What *does* matter, though, is the perception of the community; that's what you need to keep in mind.  If your question seems subjective to them, then you have an actual problem.  Removing any semblance of subjectivity can go a long way to allowing your question to survive.

Comment: I think that is the key. "Make sure it doesn't seem subjective", so with that in mind, I edited the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to. But if the system is telling you your question is likely a subjective question, you should probably listen to it, because the community (especially on SO) can be pretty harsh and close it down real fast if you are not careful (and I don't see this as a bad thing at all).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.