# How can I avoid the dreaded "Subjective" warning on ServerFault?

Tags: support, subjective, subjective-warning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)
>   [What algorithm does StackOverflow use to determine if a question may be subjective?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-algorithm-does-stackoverflow-use-to-determine-if-a-question-may-be-subjecti)

[The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed. http://shog9.com/subjective-warning.png](http://shog9.com/subjective-warning.png)

What did I do wrong? I just typed up a title for my question, went to enter the question itself, and *bam* BIG SCARY RED WARNING!

[Return to FAQ Index](https://serverfault.com/questions/8324/how-does-serverfault-work-the-community-faq)

Comment: Don't use the word "best" in a subject title - it connotes subjective question.  Voting to close as Not IT Related.  (as if I could...)

Comment: Voting to close as "Belongs on UserVoice" ... wait, I can't!

Comment: Why are you asking meta questions? Don't you know better from SO?

Comment: @Juan: yes, i do. But i also enjoy poking around and seeing what's new / different... and the beta period seems like a perfect opportunity for that. I fully expect every question I ask here to quietly disappear long before the site goes live.

Comment: @Juan: This is a SFFAQ post...I don't think Shog9 is being deadly serious.

Comment: @TheTXI: I'm pretty sure Shog9is quite the deadly guy.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/faq has a link to a search of questions tagged sffaq-official, so obviously they see the need for some features of the site to be documented by us.

Comment: What about "preferred" or "optimal" or "least bad"? :P

Comment: "Barely adequate" appears to work...

Comment: @Shog9 Please keep in mind the purpose of the beta is to fill content on the site before it goes life, Jeff rarely does a DB Cleanup before launching. This was the case with SO.

Comment: BAM! Time to stop bringing reddit memes here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't use the following words in a subject title - it connotes subjective question.

- Best
- Worst
- Hardest
- You
- Your
- Favorite
- Favourite

[Jeff posted the regex](http://serverfault.uservoice.com/pages/17382-general/suggestions/179922-remove-subjective-question-warning) in uservoice (As of May 2, 2009):

```
Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\bbest\b|\bworst\b|\bhardest\b|\byour?\b|\bfavou?rite\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It is important to note that avoiding the above words does not make your question any less subjective - "Best management tool" is inherently subjective - the warning is not there to tell you to avoid certain words, but to avoid the question altogether, or to re-word it so it can be evaluated objectively and measurably so that the answer is the same for everyone in your situation.

-Adam

Comment: also, hardest: http://serverfault.uservoice.com/pages/17382-general/suggestions/179922-remove-subjective-question-warning

Comment: basically, anything here: http://www.najle.com/idaft/

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, well, mine got closed even if it didn't had "best" in the subject. I think all this is way to "subjective" for a beta so I will probably stay away ... at least until it will be out of beta :)

Comment: Others' interpretation of subjectivity will not change when the beta period ends.

Answer (score 0):

This feature only exist due to the enormous karma boost you get when you use these words. Making people talk about there belief system or experience is the most joyful thing in the world for a geek, why take it way from us SO? This is why computers are so fun.