# Which automatic improvement checks are performed when writing a question?

Tags: support, review, questions, asking-questions

Before posting a question on a Stack Exchange site, I hit the *"Review your question"* button. Then, on the right side bar, a message is displayed:

> Step 2: Review your question
>
> ###### ✅  Your question is ready to publish!
>
> Our automated system checked for ways
>       to improve your question and found none.

In my (admittedly few) questions on Stack Exchange, I never received advice for improvement in this step.

So I wonder, what are these automated checks and what shall they prevent us from? If they are only to assure that we have included a title, a question, and a tag, then isn't the labeling as "improvement" a bit too much?

Comment: I can only find one example of a warning in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344513/369802), so it's not just checking for title, body and a tag... I must admit I've never seen that warning, or any other ones (if there are any) myself either. It is customizable per site though, so there probably isn't an exhaustive list anywhere.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell How precisely do you infer from the referenced post that it is not merely checking for title, body, and tag? These three (title, body, tag) are precisely the errors which I spot in the post you referenced.

Comment: There are two screenshots under a header that says *"Reviewing a question, with errors (shown inline) and warnings (shown on the right side):"*. The screenshot on the right, [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZngH.png) shows two errors (missing post body and tags) *and* a warning about the title not being discriptive enough :) Further down, it is explained what is customizable per site, and the post lists: *"**The warning text shown in the "Review your question" sidebar**, regex-based (seen with the default text in screenshot 4, and with custom text on screenshot 5)."*

Comment: There's a [title check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20014/1017231) for "subjectivity"

Comment: Ah, thank you! I had not recognized the text "Be specific and imagine you're asking a question to another person" (which I suppose is the warning you mean) as a warning.

Comment: This is a somewhat complex question because the answer will depend on each site - there are some overarching ones that exist network wide but many of them are per-site. :) I'm not sure how easy it will be to compile but I can see whether we can find a list that makes sense to be public. :)

Comment: @Catija Although such a list would still be interesting for me, I acknowledge that it is not very important. The comments so far have given me a helpful idea of what happens.