# How does Stack Overflow achieve its subjective check on titles?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, subjective

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)

I'm very curious about how people think Stack Overflow is determining whether or not a question is subjective and highlighting it once you've entered the title.  I'd like to build a similar capability but wouldn't know where to start.  The AJAX callbacks, HTML and stuff is easy ... but analysis the question itself seems to be quite complicated.

Comment: @Jherico - beat me to adding the subjective tag :)

Comment: How is that possibily not programming related?  I'm looking for a code sample to do this.  Is it regex?  Is it a natural language processor.  The magic of StackOverflow is waning.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work

Comment: @unknown: if we hadn't migrated it, it'd be more difficult to point out the many questions that already address this (such as the one Pesto linked to). SO-specific questions belong on Meta; if you didn't intend this to be specific to SO, then you shouldn't have phrased your question the way you did...

Comment: look for words like "best"

Answer (score 0):

Compare the words in the title to words in titles of questions that have been closed as subjective.  If, say, 30% (adjust as necessary) of the words match you might have a winner.