# How does the subjective question detector work?

Tags: discussion, subjective, subjective-warning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)

When you're writing a question, the system will show you a red bar with a warning if the question looks subjective.

Subjective or non-programming questions (e.g., *What is your favourite programming language?*) seem to be easily recognized.

How, exactly, is this done?  Heuristics, algorithms, machine learning?

I'm amazed!

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work

Comment: Duplicate. It's a Regex. Answered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work/4435#4435

Comment: Well, no need to click that link. Jeff's answer fits in a comment field: `return Regex.IsMatch(s, @"\bbest\b|\bworst\b|\bhardest\b|\byour?\b|\bfavou?rite\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: @Mehrdad: hah, 5 seconds :)

Answer (score 2):

[Jeff uses this regex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work/4435#4435):

```
return Regex.IsMatch(s, 
@"\bbest\b|\bworst\b|\bhardest\b|\byour?\b|\bfavou?rite\b", 
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure it just detects words like "favo[u]rite" and "best". I've not seen it detect a non-programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Having the word "best" in the title triggers it.