# determine question likely to be closed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)

How does SOFU determine that "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed."?

Comment: it took 16 months to identify a duplicate. thought provoking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm of the understanding that it looks for a few specific keywords (like "best") in the title. Try writing a nonsense title with "best" in it and hit Tab, then go back and change "best" to "biggest".

**Update**: Here's the definitive answer, from Jeff: [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)

Comment: I think that's how it determines it as well. Considering the warning is "the question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed", I think it just scans the title for common subjective words (since Stack Overflow is meant for questions being answered and not discussions).

Comment: this appears more correct then my guess, but I still think the way I thought makes more sense(the system learns).

Answer (score 0):

It looks at the matched questions for a high ratio of closed:not-closed.

Comment: this is a guess based on observation.

Comment: the title "What's your question? Be clear about what what an agreeing and disagreeing answer would be." has 10 closed questions in the 25 listed, so by this theory the ratio is no higher then 10:25(closed:total).

Comment: "Be clear about what what an agreeing and answer would be." has a ratio of 8:25, and does not give the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Not just that. It also looks for keywords like "you"
For example,

```
How would you do something in somelanguage in the best possible manner
```

returns the alert

```
How would you do something in somelanguage
```

returns the alert; while

```
How to do something in somelanguage
```

does not return the alert

Comment: sorry, missed it