# The subjective filter question is contributing to the decline of the English language

Tags: discussion, subjective-warning

The subjective filter warns against "How do you memoize a value that may be nil?", but not against "How to memoize a value that may be nil?".

I used to wonder why so many people used the latter. Now I know it's [Jeff's fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work/4435#4435)!

Plz hlp. The saving of the English language is urgent.

Comment: Do you mean *memorize*?

Comment: @dboarman: I'm not sure if that was a joke or serious, but I was referring to memoize: [Wikipedia says it's perferctly cromulent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: It was intended to be tongue in cheek...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English language started going downhill long before any of the SE sites. While I empathize with your desire to promote keen grammatical skills, there are other media at fault and we shouldn't rely on the subjective filter.

**EDIT:**
Thank you, Bill, for that *grammatical* correction.

Comment: Media.  There are other *media* at fault.  ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Bill: I concur.

Comment: I could hardly resist.  :)