# Why is you subjective?

Tags: discussion, subjective-warning

(Catchy title, eh?)

I am asking the following on the photo.SE site:

> How do you change from portrait to landscape in Lightroom

DANGER! DANGER! This appears to be subjective and is likely to be closed.

If I ask the following radically different question:

> How do I change from portrait to landscape in Lightroom

... there is no problem.

So, like the title says: Why is "you" subjective?

(And [here's the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work/4435#4435) where Jeff spills the regex)

Comment: Why the hating against you? You was Time person of the year in 2006!

Comment: We also give Nobel peace prizes to terrorists. I don't put much stake in these things.

Answer (score 6):

If you're asking someone "how do you do foo?" a common implication is "how do you, **as opposed to other people**, do foo?" Such a questions often have a large-to-infinite number of possible answers, with no single answer or group of answers being correct.

The kinds of questions that are asked in "how do I do foo?" format are more likely to be objective, although there are certainly cases of "you questions" being objective and "I questions" being subjective. The difference is just a quirk of how language is commonly used.

Comment: Well, I was going to answer saying pretty much the same thing, but you answered and summarized it much better.

Comment: @Troggy, as always, I immediately regretted hitting "Post Your Answer" and went back to add more clarification. Sorry to ruin the "two sentences" part of your comment.

Comment: Only programmers would draw such a literal distinction. I think it's pretty normal for people to ask "How do you do [x]" instead of "How do I do [x]"?

Comment: If we *really* want to be literal... "How do I foo?" Simple. I don't. Because I don't know how. That's why I was asking.

Comment: @Popular Now my comment will work, unless you radically change your answer.

Comment: @Jon On the same token, you're asking how to foo literally because you want to know how *you* can foo. So, you don't particularly care how *I* foo, because the whole point is for you to learn how to foo. Thus, you ask how you foo, in the form "How do I foo" as spoken by you.

Comment: I pitty you foos.