# Why does a warning flag appear on this question while composing it?

Tags: support, warning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the automatic subjective filter work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)

I was part way through composing a question when I received the warning shown in the screenshot. What has triggered this warning - I don't believe it is subjective; the question matters to me; but obviously there is something about it that has triggered an automatic alert (the low quality filter?). I have not actually posted this question yet, though I have composed it and have it ready for posting.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your question title contains the word "[YOU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work/4435#4435)"

Comment: Thanks - I'll amend it and then delete this question - your link makes it clear this is a duplicate.