# Should we warn on "should"?

Tags: discussion, title, quality-filter, subjective

It just occurred to me that a large portion of the questions containing the word "should" in their titles are — or should be — closed as not constructive. Questions with titles containing "should I" are almost exclusively problematic.

Here are the newest questions on Stack Overflow containing "[should](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3ashould)" and "[should I](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3a%22should%20i%22)."

When used by askers, the word "should" is basically short for "give me your opinion on this." A good Stack Exchange question is far more likely to use "does" or "will" instead. Granted, when used by answerers, "should" has a different meaning, but that's irrelevant here.

Should we add "should" or "should I" to the list of phrases checked by [the "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed" filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-does-the-automatic-subjective-filter-work)? This filter is only a warning, not a block, so it shouldn't stop "good subjective" posts.

Comment: Here is another one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96162/should-we-warn-on-should

Comment: @Gamecat: +1 for irony.

Comment: The wording of the title was quite intentional. I am inviting opinions and discussion here, after all.

Comment: Interestingly, I found this question after ending up walking through the flag history of a user who'd apparently searched for "should" and flagged his way down the list... Can't say I'm all that impressed with the results.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to not be a problem on every site. From Gaming, we have 98 open results for "should" in the title, consisting of items like the following. There are 10 closed, just for statistical completion.

- [What race should I genocide?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17030/what-race-should-i-genocide) - What races you *could* genocide is helpful, but not as helpful as knowing what races you should genocide to make things easier for yourself.
- [When should I start drinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/when-should-i-start-drinking) - Barring the obvious appeal of the title, the question itself is "When should I start using potions", which again, there is strategic advantage towards when it is a good time or not.
- [When should I focus my unit's fire?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/when-should-i-focus-my-units-fire) - I think the trend of timing/selection playing a key point in gameplay strategy should be clear by now.
- [What items should be saved for turn-ins?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9358/what-items-should-be-saved-for-turn-ins) - As such, let's pick a different example. This is an example in which the highlight is in what is most profitable, moreso than all that is possible. Hence, should.

I could list a lot more. A lot of it falls into a basic practice - sometimes what someone *should* do is far more important and has a pretty logical and gameplay reasoning behind it, that far outweighs merely asking what one "can" or "may" do. Sometimes it comes from a matter of the timing of engaging in a strategy, it could matter with the actual structure of the approach, or it may simply be a matter of understanding what is effective.

Some of these could be rephrased with a different word, but that feels extremely unnecessary, and quite discomforting.

I imagine that RPG probably has a similar relationship with this word. It's a vital style of question in a few cases, and I'd rather not have to *force* an exemption on some sites in order to accomodate having this filter as a baseline. It's not a block, but getting warned for a valid question (especially with a statistically greater number of valid questions) is pretty aggravating.

Comment: I agree. Using _should_ is just a matter of style. Somebody says "What should I wear?"; somebody else says "What can I wear?" That doesn't mean the first question is subjective, and the other is not.